In iceberg sink connector config, how to find length of string for a particular column using Transforms
"transforms.filterValue.type": "io.confluent.connect.transforms.Filter$Value",
"transforms": "filterValue",
"transforms.filterValue.filter.type": "include",
"transforms.filterValue.filter.condition": "$[?(@.name.length() == 2)]",

My intention is to filter out records whose name has length of 2. This doesn't seem to work and iceberg sink connector doesn't process any records. I have tried doing it with .size and .size() (did not work). In this Doc, it does support length of string but it doesn't give any example
